# How do I configure and use KStem in java?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, stemming

I want to stem the words in my document and have zeroed in on KStem. I am working in Eclipse and have configured Lucene by downloading the lucene-core jar file to the lib folder and adding it to the build path. I similarly did this for the KStem jar file. However I am unable to find any examples or documentation on how to use the KStem library in my java code. Do I need to setup Solr for that - not entirely sure what that is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to configure KStem to be picked up by Lucene / SOLR in your schema (in the field type that will have the contents of your documents) and only send the docs for indexing from your code. The rest of the magic (including tokenization / stemming / stop word removal / etc) happens inside Lucene / SOLR (depending on which processing steps you configure them to apply to your documents). See this how to configure KStem in SOLR: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/Kstem

In short, Lucene is the powerful indexing and retrieval library, that is used inside SOLR, which, in turn, is the fully-blown search server.

If you need the features, like faceted search, autocomplete, sharding, replication etc, then install and configure Solr. If not, e.g., if your goal is to have some relatively small index of documents, which can be quickly re-built and you would like to organize the search from within your own app, then use Lucene as a java library.

How to use KStemmer inside one's code:

```
private final KStemmer stemmer = new KStemmer();
// char[] term = ...
stemmer.stem(term, len);
```

You will have to split your document contents to a list of terms yourself.

This is how KStemmer is used inside Lucene: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/KStemFilter.java

Note, that KStemmer class is part of Lucene's current trunk (org.apache.lucene.analysis.en): http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/KStemmer.java

Comment: I want to specifically use the stemming function of KStem. Basically I want to implement this method - GetStemmedWords(documentText) in my java code. And I could not find any KStem documentation that tells which methods to call for this.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. But I am still unable to configure KStem in Eclipse. I have added the Lucene-core jar file to the build path and it works. But even after adding the KStem.jar file to the build path, the KStemmer class is not detected.

Comment: @AakarGupta you need lucene-analyzers-common jar, see my update in the end of the post, e.g. in Solr 4.0.0-BETA it is: lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar